# PHP Laravel Route

Tags: php, laravel

Can anyone tell me why it keeps saying that a parameter is missing for my route?

```
Route::get('delete/{id}',[
    'uses' => 'PostController@getDestroy',
    'as' => 'admin.index'
]);
```

This is my code on the view:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <p> <a href="{{ route('admin.index', ['id']) }}">Delete</a> </p>
@endforeach
```

It keeps displaying this error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.index] [URI: admin/delete/{id}]

Comment: Why would you use `admin.index` as the name for a route which deletes a resource?

Comment: And why would you use GET instead of literally ANYTHING else on a route which deletes a resource?

Comment: sorry this is my very first time using laravel

Comment: @premira Check out this tutorial: https://www.udemy.com/php-with-laravel-for-beginners-become-a-master-in-laravel/learn/v4/overview 
It's great!

Comment: Can you post the entire function within the controller. My assumption is you haven't passed `$id` into the function..

Answer (score 0):

you have to give value to id

```
<p> <a href="{{ route('admin.index', ['id' => 1]) }}">Delete</a> </p>
```

Comment: <p> <a href="{{ route('admin.index', $id) }}">Delete</a> </p>

Comment: @afsalc plase update your answer. This is the correct format. Maybe add a link to the manual as well

Comment: neither one is working i try looking at other tutorials too yet I'm still getting the same result